# Packages droped after DNAT from Broadcast to Unicast

Tags: iptables, nat

I have my normal network (192.168.1.0/24) and IoT network (192.168.2.0/24) seprated on different vlans (devices switch0 and switch0.30 respectively).
My firewall is setup so that clients from the normal network can access devices on the IoT network but not the other way around.
All this is setup on a Ubiquity edgerouter X.

Now I have a new IoT device that has a companion android app. The App works fine when I connect my android device to the IoT network.

For discovery the App sends a empty UDP-Package to 255.255.255.255 on Port 9987. The device then answers with a empty unicast-Package to the source IP. This way the app knows the IP of the device an can communicate directly over another port.

I want to also use this app when my android device is connected to my normal network. This discovery mechanism obviously does not work in this setup because these two networks are different broadcast domains. The router will never route the broadcast to the other network.

I added the following rule via iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i switch0 -p udp --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.183:9987
```

When I then start the app I can see the packages matching the rule with:

```
iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -v
```

When I monitor incomming traffic with `tcpdump -i switch0 port 9987` I can see the package incomming. But I can never see the package exiting through switch0.30 via `tcpdump -i switch0.30 port 9987`.

As `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` all show `0` I would think that the package (after beeing NATed) will next enter the `FORWARD` chain in `filter` table. Therefore I added a LOG there:

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -p UDP --dport 9987 -j LOG
```

but the package counts on that rule stay at 0.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I feel like while the rule might indeed be matched, the DNAT target itself will ignore non-unicast traffics, because it wouldn't really make sense for it not to. (I don't think DNAT is a way to implement what you want.)

Comment: It might be that DNAT is not the right tool. I for one I don't need connection tracking for this package. On the other hand, I can not think of what might be the correct tool. socat for example will always use the source IP of the router. This will also not help as the package has to reach the originating Android device.